# Is DistributedUniqueTimeProvider from net.openhft.chronicle.bytes thread-safe?

Tags: java, chronicle

Following the article https://chronicle.software/unique-timestamp-identifiers/,
I have checked the implementation of **DistributedUniqueTimeProvider.currentTimeNanos**
method.

```
    long time = provider.currentTimeNanos();
    long time0 = bytes.readVolatileLong(LAST_TIME);
    long timeN = timestampFor(time) + hostId;

    if (timeN > time0 && bytes.compareAndSwapLong(LAST_TIME, time0, timeN))
        return timeN;

    return currentTimeNanosLoop();
```

By default, it uses **SystemTimeProvider**

If we look inside **net.openhft.chronicle.core.time.SystemTimeProvider#currentTimeNanos**

```
    long nowNS = System.nanoTime();
    long nowMS = currentTimeMillis() * NANOS_PER_MILLI;
    long estimate = nowNS + delta;

    if (estimate < nowMS) {
        delta = nowMS - nowNS;
        return nowMS;

    } else if (estimate > nowMS + NANOS_PER_MILLI) {
        nowMS += NANOS_PER_MILLI;
        delta = nowMS - nowNS;
        return nowMS;
    }
    return estimate;
```

we can see that it uses non-volatile, non-atomic variable

```
    private long delta = 0;
```

So the question is:
Is **DistributedUniqueTimeProvider.currentTimeNanos** thread-safe after all? If yes, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `delta` is an estimate of the difference between the wall clock and the monotonic clock. In the worst case, this could be up to 1 ms in different threads as there is always at least one check of milliseconds vs nanoseconds. However, when used with the `DistributedUniqueTimeProvider` which has a full memory barrier and it's own enforcement of a monotonically increasing value, it won't be significant

The reason this memory barrier check is dropped is to reduce the cost of this operation by about 20%